# Is this a valid use of l'Hospital's Rule? Can it be used recursively?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x}{x^2}$$

Since this evaluates to an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ we use l'Hospital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{2x}$$

Since this also evaluates to an indeterminate form $\frac{2}{0}$ we use l'Hospital's Rule again:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{2}=0$$

I know that I could have simply divided both numerator and denominator by $x$ to get the same result. This is just an example to ask the question: Can l'Hospital's Rule be used recursively?

EDIT: Sorry, I messed up my example. I cannot think of a good example right now but the question still stands. Can one use l'Hospital's Rule recursively?

Comment: The form $\frac{2}{0}$ is not really indeterminate. It's $\pm \infty$ (which is still slightly indeterminate, but nowhere _near_ as indeterminate as $\frac00$). So no L'Hospital. L'Hospital is for $\frac{0}{0}$ and $\frac{\pm\infty}{\infty}$, and even then there are cases where you need to be careful.

Comment: @Arthur: You lazy goose. You say absurdly brilliant things which you should expand and post as an answer but don't.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}$ does not even exist! Here, Left Hand Limit $\neq$ Right Hand Limit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**L'Hôpital's Rule**

Assuming that the following conditions are true:

1. $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be differentiable
2. $\frac{d}{dx}g(x)\neq 0$
3. $\lim\limits_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{0}{0}\mbox{ or }\lim\limits_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$

Then,
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim\limits_{x\to c} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}{\frac{d}{dx}g(x)}=L $$
Where $c$ and $L$ is any real number or $\pm\infty$.

So to answer your questions, **yes, L'Hôpital's rule can be used repeatedly, provided that all of the above conditions are met**. Since your example doesn't meet the aforementioned conditions, L'Hôpital's rule is **not** applicable.

Here is a case where L'Hôpital's rule is applicable multiple times,
$$ 
\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{e^x}{x^2}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}
$$
Since the conditions are met, we can apply L'Hôpital's rule
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}e^x}{\frac{d}{dx}x^2}= \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^x}{2x}= \frac{\infty}{\infty}
$$
Notice that the conditions are met again, so now
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}e^x}{\frac{d}{dx}2x}= \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^x}{2}= \infty
$$
Therefore 
$$ 
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{x^2}=\infty
$$

Answer (score 7):

You're correct till the third step, although you can write $\dfrac1x+\dfrac1x = \dfrac2x$ instead of taking LCM.

However in the third step, $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{2}{2x}$ is not an indeterminate form (not $\dfrac00$). Therefore, it's <s>illegal</s> inapplicable to use  L'Hospital's Rule there.

Answer to 'recursive' question: I don't know what you mean by 'recursively', but it can be used repetatively.

Consider $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = \lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{2x} = \lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos x}{2} = \dfrac12$$ by using  L'Hospital's Rule two times.

Comment: "Illegal"? I doubt any police officers are gonna be busting down the OP's door any time soon.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure illegal is used in the context of math. Still, which word do you propose in lieu?

Comment: @taninamdar, inapplicable?

Comment: It's not illegal. It's just wrong. The same as saying $1+1=3$ isn't warrant for arrest, but it's incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rule only if you are calculating $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $\lim f(x) = \lim g(x) = 0$ or $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x) = \infty$. The functions in $\frac2 {2x}$ do not satisfy this demand.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2}{2x}$ is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TheGame: Part of the question (in the post title) was 'Is this a valid use of L'Hopital's rule?'

Comment: I posted that because I believed that given its length, this would be more appropriate as a comment. You might consider completing it by adding what the limit, or something like that :)

Comment: @TheGame: I would say that often very short answers can be quite illuminating.  I figure if it makes the character minimum for a MSE answer, it's (potentially) long enough.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I see what you did there.

You tried to claim that: $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {2}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\dfrac {2}{x}\times\dfrac{x}{x}\right)$ and as that was an indeterminant form you could apply l'Hospital's rule.

l'Hopital's only works if you *cannot remove* indeterminacy by cancellation.   It doesn't work if you *introduce* indeterminacy through multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but make sure to work the correct way around when writing it out. L'Hopital's rule says $f'(x)/g'(x)$ converges and $f(x)/g(x)$ is an indeterminate form, then $f(x)/g(x)$ has the same limit. So if you want to iterate it say twice and take advantage of $f''(x)/g''(x)$ being nice, you need to first apply it it $f'(x)/g'(x)$ by showing $f'(x)/g'(x)$ is an indeterminate form and $f''(x)/g''(x)$ converges to deduce $f'(x)/g'(x)$ converges, then you have enough information to apply the rule to to $f(x)/g(x)$.